# Add Database specific hints to BRIO queries/reports

Tags: sql-server, brio

Is there a way to add db specific hints to Brio queries.

I'm looking to improve the performance of a bunch of brio reports that connect to a MS SQL database to pull data. Brio seems to be creating SQL queries with not hints like

> WITH (NOLOCK)

This leads to these generated select queries blocking updates to the table. So is there a way to make Brio add the WITH (NOLOCK) hint to SQL queries?

Comment: "This leads to these generated select queries blocking," - I don't think it does.....and if you are asking how to add WITH(NOLOCK), that's rarely the right solution; better indexing is.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm being told that, when you run a select query on a table that takes time to run with out the hint, it prevents an update on the table until it completes its run.

Comment: i suspect you have an XY problem

Comment: Lol, could be. The DB is a reporting DB, and people run all sort of unexpected queries, So planning the correct indexing would be very difficult. On top the data is synced from prod to the reporting server every 15 mins. So that is the reason for a NOLOCK hint.